Recommender System - Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) is providing random results
Sometimes, the quality of the output is simply assessed by eyeballing it. Looking at the examples provided below, if we use simple intuition it's clear that the expected user ratings are 2 and 3 (please refer to the empty data cells).
The examples are simplified - I've used much larger datasets and still harvested the same results.
Table 1

    Users   Movie 1 Movie 2 Movie 3
    
    1       -       3       4
    
    2       2       3       4
    
    3       2       3       4
    
Table 2
    
    Users   Movie 1 Movie 2 Movie 3
    
    1       -       3       3
    
    2       3       3       3
    
    3       3       3       3

The ALS model delivers exactly these ratings, but the SVD model fails miserably. Does anyone have any idea why that is? Why would we get results other than 2 and 3 using SVD for user predicted results?
